# Using Zabbix to monitor a forward proxy server

Tags: bash, proxy, zabbix

I need to be notified when our proxy server goes down.  Currently I have a bash script that tests the proxy functionality:

```
CHECKRESULT=(curl -s --proxy 4.83.58.205:80 checkip.dyndns.com | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/<\/body><\/html>\r//g';)


if [ "$CHECKRESULT" != "4.83.58.205" ]
                                then
                                echo "FAILED: proxy 4.83.58.205 returned \" $CHECKRESULT\""
                                FAILEDCOUNT=$(($FAILEDCOUNT+1))
                                fi
```

I would like to use Zabbix to run a similar check, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zabbix, when compiled with CURL support, can directly monitor web services including complex more steps scenarios. You can setup triggers on HTTP return code, returned data, response time...

Documentation [here](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/web_monitoring).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Web items are run from the Zabbix server, not the Zabbix agent.

Comment: Yes, complex scenarios are run from Zabbix server, but since 2.0 there are `web.page.*` items in Zabbix agent, which can do simple checks.

Comment: Thanks!  This is perfect, from the doc: "To use HTTP proxy, set the http_proxy environment variable for Zabbix server user. For example, http_proxy=http://proxy_ip:proxy_port."  Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your existing script works well and does what you need, what you want to setup is an external check as described at http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external

Your script goes in the directory specified in your zabbix configuration for ExternalScripts - likely something like /etc/zabbix/externalscripts.  Make sure it has appropriate permissions for the zabbix user to be able to execute it.

In the template or  host, create a new item, and set the type to external check, and set the key to the name of your script.

Then create a trigger that looks for the "FAILED" line and alerts you.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to go with the "web monitoring" solution baked into Zabbix, but I know I'm going to end up using this as well.  Great info for a Zabbix noob.